# SpaCy STOP_WORDS for keywords still returning unwanted words

Tags: nlp, spacy, streamlit, stop-words

I am trying to filter out keywords from spaCy AI's STOP_WORDS using the below code, which I believe should work. However words contained in both the spaCy word list and my own when added are still returned to the user? Can you spot where I have go wrong as I am blind to it, please!?

```
import spacy
from spacy.lang.en.stop_words import STOP_WORDS
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_pages, extract_text
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import sqlite3
import streamlit as st

# Load the pre-trained spaCy model
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

# Define a set of custom stop words
STOP_WORDS |= {"stop1","wordzz"}

# Define a function to segment the document into smaller segments
def segment_document(doc, min_sentence_length=10, max_sentence_length=50, max_segment_length=220):
    segments = []
    current_segment = ""
    current_length = 0
    
    for sentence in doc.sents:
        if len(sentence) < min_sentence_length:
            continue
        if len(sentence) > max_sentence_length:
            continue
        
        if current_length + len(sentence) > max_segment_length:
            segments.append(current_segment.strip())
            current_segment = ""
            current_length = 0
        
        current_segment += sentence.text
        current_length += len(sentence)
    
    if current_segment:
        segments.append(current_segment.strip())
    
    return segments

# Define a function to extract keywords and phrases from a text segment
def extract_keywords(segment, num_keywords=15):
    doc = nlp(segment)
   
    # Extract named entities and noun chunks
    entities = [entity.text for entity in doc.ents if entity.label_ != "DATE"]
    noun_chunks = [chunk.text for chunk in doc.noun_chunks]
    
    # Combine entities and noun chunks into a single list
    keywords = entities + noun_chunks
    
    # Filter out stop words
    filtered_keywords = [keyword for keyword in keywords if keyword not in STOP_WORDS]
    
    # Create a tf-idf vectorizer and fit it to the filtered keywords
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
    vectorizer.fit_transform(filtered_keywords)
    
    # Get the feature names and tf-idf scores for each keyword
    feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names_out()
    tfidf_scores = vectorizer.idf_
    
    # Combine the feature names and scores into a dictionary and sort by score
    keyword_scores = {}
    for i in range(len(feature_names)):
        keyword_scores[feature_names[i]] = tfidf_scores[i]
    
    sorted_keywords = sorted(keyword_scores.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    
    # Return the top num_keywords
    top_keywords = [keyword[0] for keyword in sorted_keywords[:num_keywords]]
    
    return top_keywords

    

# Define the Streamlit app
def app():
    st.title("Document Segmenter")
    st.write("This app segments a long multi-page document into smaller, coherent segments of text and extracts important keywords and phrases from each segment.")
    
    # Allow the user to upload a file
    doc_file = st.file_uploader("Upload a document", type=["pdf", "txt"])
    
    
    if doc_file is not None:
        # Load the document using spaCy
        text_input = extract_text(doc_file)
        doc = nlp(text_input)

        
        # Segment the document into smaller segments
        segments = segment_document(doc)
        
        # Extract keywords and phrases from each segment and display the results to the user
        for i, segment in enumerate(segments):
            st.write(f"Segment {i+1}:")
            st.write(segment)
            st.write("---")
            st.write("Keywords and phrases:")
            keywords = extract_keywords(segment)
            for keyword in keywords:
                st.write(keyword)
            st.write("===")
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app()
```

Words initially identified as keywords which can be found in the STOP_WORDS list should be dropped and not returned to the user.